# play store rejected app due non-certified ads SDK

Tags: android, reactjs, expo

I published my app `react-expo` app on play store but it rejected the app, giving following warning.=

**Issue: Violation of Families Policy Requirements**

We have detected that your app includes non-certified ad SDKs or SDKs that are not approved for use in child-directed services. Any SDKs used in the app must be appropriate for use in child-directed services. Additionally, apps that solely target children must not contain any SDKs that are not approved for use in child-directed services, including ads SDKs. Apps in the Designed for Families program must only use ad SDKs that have certified their compliance with the Families Ads Program.

So how should I tackle with this issue. I also removed location permission by just inserting empty array to `permissions=[]`:

```
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon2.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
        
      },
      "package": "com.adityasonawane.abcdKids",
      "permissions":[]
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

`expo build:android` and `expo build:ios` is the old way to build your project.

If you use `eas-cli`, you will not run into this problem. To install `eas-cli`, run:

```
npm i -g eas-cli
```

Then run `eas build -p android` or `eas build -p ios` in the project directory.

See [Limitations](https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/why-not-expo/#limitations-of-expo-go-and-the-classic) in the Expo documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you are not promoting any third-party apps or things in your application. It also depends on the type of application which you are deploying.

You can also enable the option of not suitable for families and children. This might also help in getting it accepted.

Comment: i am not promoting any third party product in this app. And age group below 13 is for family program So i also tried to select age group above 13, but play store says that please select family age group because your app is for children.

Comment: and I also think that react-native community is not active. Because many of the people raised same issue on there issue forum but still it is unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the problem
Add the below code to your file beginning your method.

More info published in the AdMob Participate in the Families Self-Certified Ads SDK Program

Policy Details ->
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12289447?visit_id=638053250716856067-2584751559&rd=1

Code Sample ->
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6223431#zippy=%2Ccode-sample-for-implementation-in-apps-for-everyone-including-children-and-families

```
    //AdMob Apps for everyone, including children and families policy
    RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration = 
    MobileAds.getRequestConfiguration()
            .toBuilder()
            .setTagForChildDirectedTreatment(
                    RequestConfiguration.TAG_FOR_CHILD_DIRECTED_TREATMENT_TRUE)
            .setMaxAdContentRating(RequestConfiguration.MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_G)
            .build();
    MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(requestConfiguration);
    //End
```

[image]
App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nandeproduction.easyrecharger